# nifi configuring variable to set and unset values

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to build a nifi process which work like similar to ETL process, (i.e) The nifi process will be executed once in a day and pick a file from certain directory. The file contains a date and i want to store that as a environment variable, the next day when the process runs i want to compare the date from the file with the date i stored in Variable, is there a way we can achieve this in NIFI without storing the date value in any table? I tried from storing in a file which works perfectly, but is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

@Jai,
You can do that by using NiFi by using

> 1.Pick a file from Certain Directory  use GetHDFS,List/FetchHDFS (or) Getfile,List/FetchFile
>   2.Extract date  Use Extract Text processor add new property with regex that can extract the date as an attribute.
>   3.Store the extracted attribute Use Distributemapcache Processor to store the Extracted Date attribute.
>
> 4.For next day run use  Fetch Distributecachemap processor to pull the stored date and compare the variable with already existed variable in
>   distributemapcache processor.